Resumed function 'beginRound()' after await, but script is gone. Godot Await Error
I'm experiencing an error with await being triggered multiple times inside a loop.
What the code is supposed to do is loop through all the empires, telling them to take their turns and then awaiting their completion before triggering the next empire. This works for the first turn (the player's turn), but when an AI tries to call endTurn(), I get the error:
E 0:01:08:0911   Map.gd:419 @ endTurn(): Resumed function 'beginRound()' after await, but script is gone.  
    At script: res://scripts/HostGameMenu.gd:197  
    <C++ Error>    Method/function failed. Returning: Variant()  
    <C++ Source>   modules/gdscript/gdscript_function.cpp:197 @ resume()  
    <Stack Trace>  Map.gd:419 @ endTurn()  
    Tribe.gd:221 @ takeTurn()  
    Map.gd:414 @ beginNewTurn()  
    HostGameMenu.gd:196 @ beginRound()  
    Map.gd:419 @ endTurn()  
    Map.gd:1912 @ endEmpireTurn()  

Script One Functions:
func beginRound():
    for i in range(empireTurnOrder.size()):
        empireTurnIndex = i #the only purpose this serves is being able to easily access whose turn it is for debugging from outside the for loop
        gameMap.beginNewTurn.rpc(empireTurnOrder[empireTurnIndex]) #empireTurnOrder is a PackedStringArray
        await gameMap.beginNextTurn
    gameMap.endRound.rpc() #gameMap points to the node containing Script Two

Script Two Functions:
signal beginNextTurn

@rpc("any_peer", "call_local", "reliable")
func beginNewTurn(nextEmpire: String) -> void:
    var empire = getEmpire(nextEmpire)
    if empire.playerId != -1 and empire.playerId != userEmpire.playerId: #check is only for multiplayer, which is not the case for my tests. userEmpire is a reference to the empire node (node of Script Three) that the player controls
        pass
    else:
        if empire.playerId == userEmpire.playerId:
            #UI edits, irrelevant
        empire.takeTurn() #empire points to the node(s) of Script Three

func endTurn():
    if not serverHandler.inServer or multiplayer.get_unique_id() == 1: #serverHandler points to the node of Script One. inServer will always be true for singleplayer, which I am testing
        print(is_instance_valid(serverHandler))
        emit_signal("beginNextTurn")

func endRound():
    if not serverHandler.inServer or multiplayer.get_unique_id() == 1:
        serverHandler.beginRound()

func endEmpireTurn(): #button is tied to this function
    #edits UI a little
    endTurn()

Script Three Functions:
func takeTurn():
    if playerId == -1:
        map.endTurn() #map points the node of Script Two
    else:
        #does nothing; button press will call endTurn for players

Printed Output:

True
True

Any help is appreciated. The only other posts I found about this error were people awaiting timers in _process() functions, and the answers to those questions were not exactly applicable to my situation.
Edit:
I added a function to Script One:
func turnEnded() -> void:
    print(empireTurnOrder[empireTurnIndex] + "'s turn is over.")

and connected the beginNextTurn signal to it, and it also printed successfully/correctly for both emissions of the signal, but the error didn't change.
Edit 2:
Just out of curiosity to see if it worked, I changed two functions, beginNewTurn and beginRound like so:
@rpc("any_peer", "call_local", "reliable")
func beginNewTurn(nextEmpire: String) -> bool:
    var empire = getEmpire(nextEmpire)
    if empire.playerId != -1 and empire.playerId != userEmpire.playerId:
        pass
    else:
        if empire.playerId == userEmpire.playerId:
            loadedData.get_node("ImportantMenuHub/EndTurn").set_disabled(false)
            loadedData.get_node("ResourceHUD/RaiseAll").set_disabled(false)
        empire.takeTurn()
    await beginNextTurn
    return true

func beginRound():
    for i in range(empireTurnOrder.size()):
        empireTurnIndex = i
        await gameMap.beginNewTurn(empireTurnOrder[empireTurnIndex])
    gameMap.endRound.rpc()

And this gives the error "Parameter "function" is null" on the emit_signal("beginNextTurn") line. Now, obviously, I do want my solution to be compatible with rpc function calls, but it's very strange the signal refuses to function correctly with beginRound() and beginNewTurn(). The output for this, btw, is still

true
<empire 1>'s turn is over.
true
<empire 2>'s turn is over.


I'm not sure how clear it is, so I'll outline it now, but the flow is beginRound() -> beginNewTurn() -> takeTurn() -> endTurn() -> beginNewTurn() -> ad nauseam. Originally, I had beginRound as a function that would only run one empire's turn, but it would be directly called by endTurn(). This, however, meant that the player's turn was the only thing breaking up the Stack Trace, and so if too many AI empires existed, the stack would overflow. I tried replacing the function call with a signal, but that didn't work, so now I'm stuck trying to get this to function as one loop.

Based on the error message, it looks like you're moving or deleting the node that contains the HostGameMenu.gd script at some point. Not seeing that in the provided code, but does it happen elsewhere?

The only node with a chance of being deleted/moved is the one that has Script Three assigned. You can see by the printed output that the node with Script One assigned is considered a valid instance right up to when the error happens.

Looks like that error is only caused by the awaiting script being freed. Is that node present in the tree while the game is running? The remote tree view should be able to help out with that.
If you're not freeing it anywhere that you can see, I'd scour the codebase for anywhere that you free these nodes, because one way or another it looks like that's the problem.

The node is present in the tree, and I can see it in the remote tree even as the error is taking place.

Even the script is still there, assigned to the node. I am so confused.

This is an error with Godot version 4.2.2 that has been fixed in 4.3. I'm not sure if this is an acceptable answer for this site, but it is the only one for this question.
